# Reuse a method with nested for-loops that only differs by some lines inside the inner loop

Tags: java, for-loop, refactoring

I have a java method that basically looks like this:

```
public static Map<String, List<MyObject>> myMappingMethod(List<A> listOfA, List<B> listOfB) {
    final Map<String, List<MyObject>> results = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (A objA : listOfA) {
        if (!objA.meetsSomeCriteria()) {
            continue;
        }

        for (B objB : listOfB) {
            if (!objB.meetsSomeCriteria()) {
                continue;
            }
            
            createFileWithIntermediateResultsFrom(objA, objB);   // <-- seldomly needed

            // create new List<MyObject> from objA and objB and add to results
        }
    }
    
    return results;
}
```

Now I want to basically duplicate this method and leave out the the `createFileWithIntermediateResultsFrom(objA, objB);` part cause usually I don't need that (but can't take it out, cause it is needed for like 1 %).

**How to avoid copy&paste with one line deletion and also avoid introducing some kind of "debug"-parameter?**

(If possible, I don't want to change the signature to `myMappingMethod(List<A> listOfA, List<B> listOfB, boolean createDbgFile)`)

Comment: You could write a version (call it X) of this that *does* take a debug parameter, and then have your "real" versions call X, each with a different value for the debug parameter.

Comment: If you can externalize your *isDebug* logic then you can call it directly within your method.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to do: externalizing the debug logic, so I can have my non-debug version call the debug version. But I don't know how. I thought maybe there's a pattern/best-practice for that.